# creating a list of values by iterating through lists in a method call

Tags: python, list, methods

I want to create a list of values which is the result of feeding two lists of variables (init_list and fin_list) into an equation saved in a method (yoy_eq).

I've tried to append the result of calling yoy_eq using list comprehensions which iterate through init_list and fin_list but it returns:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

How can I feed yoy_eq int from the list and not the list itself?

I've tried this:

```html
init_list = [y_2000,y_2005,y_2010]
fin_list = [y_2005,y_2010,y_2015]


def yoy_eq(init,fin):
    return (init-fin) * 100 /init


y = []

y.append(yoy_eq([i for i in init_list],[i for i in fin_list]))
```

And this:

```html
def yoy_eq(init,fin):
    return (init-fin) * 100 /init





def iterator(a):
    for i in a:
        return a
    


y.append((yoy_eq(iterator(init_list),iterator(fin_list)))
```

Comment: Your function doesn't accept lists, because you can never use `-` with list objects. No te, your list comprehensions *also* just return a list, and are a verbose equivalent of `list(init_list)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga makes some good points. Can you provide some more context for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` can iterate over the two lists, given a function that takes two arguments.

```
init_list = [y_2000,y_2005,y_2010]
fin_list = [y_2005,y_2010,y_2015]


def yoy_eq(init,fin):
    return (init-fin) * 100 /init

y = list(map(yoy_eq, init_list, fin_list))
```

or you can zip the two lists together and use a list comprehension to apply the function.

```
y = [yoy_eq(x, y) for x, y in zip(init_list, fin_list)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided would work with [*numpy*](https://numpy.org/) arrays that do elementwise arithmetic.

However, with pure Python, you need to iterate manually:

```
def yoy_eq(init,fin):
    'Return a new list combining *init* and *fin*'
    return [(init_value - fin_value) * 100 / init_value
            for init_value, fin_value in zip(init, fin)]
```

With *numpy*, the iteration happens for free:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> init = np.array([2000, 2010, 2020])
>>> fin =  np.array([2004, 2050, 2075])
>>> (init-fin) * 100 / init
array([-0.2       , -1.99004975, -2.72277228])
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that's what you looking for:

```
def yoy_eq(init, fin):
    return [
        (it1 - it2) * 100 / it1
        for it1, it2 in zip(init, fin)
    ]
```

where `it1` - is iterator of init list and `it2` - is iterator of fin list

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension, you may try this :

```
init_list = [y_2000,y_2005,y_2010]
fin_list = [y_2005,y_2010,y_2015]


def yoy_eq(init,fin):
    return (init-fin) * 100 /init


y = [yoy_eq(init_list[i], fin_list[i]) for i in range(len(init_list))]
```

or probably better:

```
y = [yoy_eq(init, fin) for init,fin in zip(init_list, fin_list)]
```